# Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 error on installing package "youtube_player_flutter: " with firebase

Tags: video, firebase-realtime-database, flutter, youtube, build.gradle

I want to store youtube links on my real time firebase database and play them on my flutter app.

I could make the connection between firebase and flutter using

```
 firebase_database: 1.0.3
  firebase_core:
```

Now I am trying to embed a youtube url (video) to my app. 
I tried following packages:

```
youtube_player_flutter: ^6.0.3+2

  flutter_youtube: "^1.1.6"
```

these packages and code works fine on my other projects where firebase is not involved. But mere installation of these packages terminates my app with:

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        39.1s
**Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1**
```

error.

I have tried changing my gradle version, flutter clean but it doesn't work.

Please help, I don't even know what causes it.

Answer (score 0):

I was on a master channel. Just changed the channel to stable. it will solve the problem. 
run:

```
flutter channel stable
```